# Access to i and j variables in Maxima's matrixmap?

Tags: matrix, maxima

I'm still a maxima newbie so bear with me. I am trying to write my own formula for calculating the adjoint of a matrix (I know maxima already has one built-in, but I was trying my own as a learning exercise). So far I have (for a 3x3 matrix):

```
/* cofactor of some submatrix of the matrix, by deleting row i and column j */
cof(i, j, M) := determinant(submatrix(i, M, j));

/* for 3 x 3 matrix */
C3(M) := matrix( [cof(1,1,M), cof(1,2,M), cof(1,3)],
                 [cof(2,1,M), cof(2,2,M), cof(2,3)],
                 [cof(3,1,M), cof(3,2,M), cof(3,3)] );

/* function for calculating adjoint sign for x at position i, j */
adj_f(i, j, x) := -1^(i+j) * x;

/* adjugate for a 3x3 matrix M */
adj3(M) := matrixmap(lambda([i,j,x], adj_f(i,j,x), transpose(C3(M))));
```

I know this probably isn't the best way of doing it; however, I was wondering if there was a way of accessing the i and j elements when using matrixmap or fullmapl?

(I'm using wxMaxima and I don't have a whole lot of lisp experience, I was trying to get away with this without touching any code).

Comment: Hahaha, oops, meant 'bear with me'.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't do it with matrixmap

```
 -- Function: matrixmap (<f>, <M>)
     Returns a matrix with element `i,j' equal to `<f>(<M>[i,j])'.

     See also `map', `fullmap', `fullmapl', and `apply'.
```

since i and j are not functions of the (i,j)-th element of M.

An imperative solution might look like the following:

```
adj3(M) :=
block([adjugate: transpose(C3(M))],
  for i: 1 thru 3 do
    for j: 1 thru 3 do
      adjugate[i,j]: adj_f(i,j,adjugate[i,j]),
  adjugate)$
```

Note that your C3 function was missing some "M"'s and adj_f needs to be

```
adj_f(i, j, x) := (-1)^(i+j) * x;
```

(otherwise it's -( (1)^(i+j) ) = -1 for all i,j).

Answer (score 1):

Try genmatrix instead of matrixmap. First argument of genmatrix is a function which takes i and j as arguments.

```
(%i2) cof (i, j, M) := determinant (submatrix (i, M, j)) $
(%i3) adj_sign (i, j) := (-1)^(i + j) $
(%i4) M : matrix([1, 2, 3], [-1, 2, 3], [1, -2, 3]) $
(%i5) my_inverse (M) := (1 / determinant (M)) * genmatrix (lambda ([i, j], cof (j, i, M) *  adj_sign (i, j)), 3, 3) $
(%i6) M1 : my_inverse (M);
(%o6) matrix([1/2,-1/2,0],[1/4,0,-1/4],[0,1/6,1/6])
```

Sorry for the late reply. Leaving this here in case someone finds it by searching.